# change multiple monitor arrangement using command line in MacOS

Tags: display, command-line, catalina

Is it possible to arrange multiple monitors using the command line or some textual setting in MacOS? I want to have finer control of how the monitors line up.

I have heard of https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer but am hoping to do this without needing to install some software.

Comment: You probably can use AppleScript to interact with Preferences but using `displayplacer` will get results quicker and easier.